# How do I fit a large equation onto one line?

Tags: math-mode

I have included a sample of my code. I would like to reduce the size of my equation so that it will fit onto one line but when I run the code I am getting an error. Any advice would be really appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath} \scalebox{0.5}{-\lambda\V_{t}^{H}+\alpha\V_{d}+1/2\V_{dd}\gamma_{t}^2+\frac{-\lambda^2{\D}_t^2\V_{x}^2-\lambda\mu{\D}_t\V_{x}^2+\lambda\varphi{\D}_t\V_{x}^2-\lambda\gamma\sigma{\D}_t\V_{x}\V_{xd}}{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}+\frac{-\lambda\mu{\D}_t\V_{x}^2-\mu^2\V_{x}^2+\mu\varphi\V_{x}^2-\mu\gamma\sigma\V_{x}\V_{xd}}{\sigma^2\V_{xx}} +\frac{-\lambda\varphi{\D}_t\V_{x}^2-\mu\varphi\V_{x}^2+\varphi^2\V_{x}^2-\gamma\sigma\varphi\V_{x}\V_{xd}}{\sigma^2\V_{xx}} +\frac{(-\lambda{\D}_t}\V_{x}-\mu\V_{x}+\varphi\V_{x}-\gamma\sigma\V_{xd})^2{2\sigma^2\V_{xx}}+\frac{-\lambda\gamma\sigma{\D}_t}\V_{x}\V_{xd}-\mu\gamma\sigma\V_{x}\V_{xd}+\gamma\sigma\varphi\V_{x}\V_{xd}-\gamma^2\sigma^2\V_{xd}^2{\sigma^2\V_{xx}} } \end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `\V` command?

Comment: A tip: select the code and hit Ctrl + K do to add proper code markup. (Blocks of code are  indented with four spaces, inline code placed between backticks.)

Comment: And  what is `\D`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no chance to be able to resizing the equation so it fits one line and remains readable.

Note: I provided dummy definitions for `\V` and `\D` and they just produce *V* and *D*.

[image]

You can use a multiline display instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\V}{V}
\newcommand{\D}{D}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{multline*}
  -\lambda\V_{t}^{H}
  +\alpha\V_{d}+1/2\V_{dd}\gamma_{t}^2
\\
  +\frac{-\lambda^2{\D}_t^2\V_{x}^2
         -\lambda\mu{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         +\lambda\varphi{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         -\lambda\gamma\sigma{\D}_t\V_{x}\V_{xd}
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  +\frac{-\lambda\mu{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         -\mu^2\V_{x}^2
         +\mu\varphi\V_{x}^2
         -\mu\gamma\sigma\V_{x}\V_{xd}
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  +\frac{-\lambda\varphi{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         -\mu\varphi\V_{x}^2
         +\varphi^2\V_{x}^2
         -\gamma\sigma\varphi\V_{x}\V_{xd}
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  +\frac{(-\lambda{\D}_t\V_{x}
          -\mu\V_{x}+\varphi\V_{x}
          -\gamma\sigma\V_{xd})^2
       }{2\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  +\frac{-\lambda\gamma\sigma{\D}_t\V_{x}\V_{xd}
         -\mu\gamma\sigma\V_{x}\V_{xd}
         +\gamma\sigma\varphi\V_{x}\V_{xd}
         -\gamma^2\sigma^2\V_{xd}^2
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\end{multline*}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, aligning the operation symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\V}{V}
\newcommand{\D}{D}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{align*}
  -\lambda\V_{t}^{H}
  &+\alpha\V_{d}+1/2\V_{dd}\gamma_{t}^2
\\
  &+\frac{-\lambda^2{\D}_t^2\V_{x}^2
         -\lambda\mu{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         +\lambda\varphi{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         -\lambda\gamma\sigma{\D}_t\V_{x}\V_{xd}
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  &+\frac{-\lambda\mu{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         -\mu^2\V_{x}^2
         +\mu\varphi\V_{x}^2
         -\mu\gamma\sigma\V_{x}\V_{xd}
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  &+\frac{-\lambda\varphi{\D}_t\V_{x}^2
         -\mu\varphi\V_{x}^2
         +\varphi^2\V_{x}^2
         -\gamma\sigma\varphi\V_{x}\V_{xd}
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  &+\frac{(-\lambda{\D}_t\V_{x}
          -\mu\V_{x}+\varphi\V_{x}
          -\gamma\sigma\V_{xd})^2
       }{2\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\\
  &+\frac{-\lambda\gamma\sigma{\D}_t\V_{x}\V_{xd}
         -\mu\gamma\sigma\V_{x}\V_{xd}
         +\gamma\sigma\varphi\V_{x}\V_{xd}
         -\gamma^2\sigma^2\V_{xd}^2
       }{\sigma^2\V_{xx}}
\end{align*}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]